# Formula to convert year to decade

Tags: c#

I am looking for a formula to convert year to decade.

Minimal year would not be below 1910 to make it more simple.

for example:

> int year=1984;

should return 80 INT

> int year 1998;

sould return 90 INT

For 2004 and 2017 (for example) it will just return 2000 and 2010.

The reason of the inconsistency after the year 2000 is because '00s, and mostly '10s (for 2010) is not understood while i need to show this input to users.

Comment: Are you sure you want to lose the "19" part for the 20th century, but keep the "20" part for the 21st century? That sounds inconsistent. It's done easily enough with an `if` statement though... could you show us what you've tried so far? The `%` operator may well be useful to you... or just divide and remultiply.

Comment: (year / 10) * 10?

Comment: @MineR How's that logical?

Comment: @MineR: Yes, except that apparently before 2000 the OP would then want to subtract 1900...

Comment: As stated in his question, a minimum year cannot be lesser than 1910. So I believe 1885 wouldn't be a problem

Comment: @Haytam ... it's an int.

Comment: @GokulanPH: Yup, I spotted that after writing the comment, so edited it :)

Comment: @MineR yes and what about 1984 and 1998?

Comment: @DaisyShipton What do you suggest than?

Comment: I can't imagine that this is what you really want, but: year < 2000 ? (year/10 * 10 - 1900) : (year / 10 * 10);

Comment: @Dror: I suggest showing what you've tried so far, and either using a consistent approach (1980, 1990, 2000, 2010 *or* 80, 90, 0, 10) or explaining why you're okay with an inconsistent approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
public static int GetDecade(int year)
{
    return year < 2000 ? (year/10 * 10 - 1900) : (year / 10 * 10);
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(1984 + " : " + GetDecade(1984)); //1984 : 80
Console.WriteLine(1991 + " : " + GetDecade(1991)); //1991 : 90
Console.WriteLine(1999 + " : " + GetDecade(1999)); //1999 : 90
Console.WriteLine(2000 + " : " + GetDecade(2000)); //2000 : 2000
Console.WriteLine(2006 + " : " + GetDecade(2006)); //2006 : 2000
Console.WriteLine(2016 + " : " + GetDecade(2016)); //2016 : 2010
```